# Your APK's version code needs to be higher than 1051

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have made game in unity and trying to upload android version But 
constantly getting this error: 
"Your APK's version code needs to be higher than 1051"

i have raised version no. as well bundle version code but ....

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Googles guide to versioning.

- https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en
- http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html

There may be some inconsistency between what you have entered
 in to **`Unity`** and what is in the **`manifest`**.